# MapReduce related - what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: mapreduce

I am new to Map-Reduce programming paradigm. So, my question may sound utter stupid to many. However, I request all to kindly bear with me.

I am trying to count number of occurrences of a **particular word** in a file. Now, I wrote following Java classes for that.

The input file for this has following entries:

```
The tiger entered village in the night the the \
Then ... the story continues...
I have put the word 'the' many times because of my own program purpose.
```

**WordCountMapper.java**

```
package com.demo.map_reduce.word_count.mapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
{
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       if(null != value) {
          final String line = value.toString();
          if(StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(line, "the")) {
             context.write(new Text("the"), new IntWritable(StringUtils.countMatches(line, "the")));
          }
       }
    }
}
```

**WordCountReducer.java**

```
package com.demo.map_reduce.word_count.reducer;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class WordCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
{
   @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
   public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          int count = 0;
      for (final IntWritable nextValue : values) {
             count += nextValue.get();
          }
          context.write(key, new IntWritable(count));
    }
}
```

**WordCounter.java**

```
package com.demo.map_reduce.word_count;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import com.demo.map_reduce.word_count.mapper.WordCountMapper;
import com.demo.map_reduce.word_count.reducer.WordCountReducer;

public class WordCounter
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String inputDataPath = "/input/my_wordcount_1/input_data_file.txt";
        final String outputDataDir = "/output/my_wordcount_1";
        try {
            final Job job = Job.getInstance();
            job.setJobName("Simple word count");
            job.setJarByClass(WordCounter.class);

            job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
            job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);

            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputDataPath));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputDataDir));

            job.waitForCompletion(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting following output when I run this program in Hadoop.

```
the 2
the 1
the 3
```

I want the reducer to result

```
the 4
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong; or I may not have understood properly. Could someone help me here?

Thanks in advance.

-Niranjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is your reduce method is not getting invoked 
To make it work just change the signature of reduce function to

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

Comment: Hi, My `reduce()` method signature is same as you mentioned. However, I also feel that the `reduce()` method is not invoked (because I am not able to see the `System.out.println()` statements in console). Do you see any other issue?

Comment: you are using org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context just change it to Context or change it to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>.Context

Comment: I got it. After changing the signature to `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>.Context`, hadoop started calling the Reducer and things fall in place. Thank you very much. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not normalizing the keywords and you are not counting the words, You are counting the lines that contains the word `the`.

Change your map logic to the following

```
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if(null != value) {
        final String line = value.toString();
        for(String word:line.split("\\s+")){
            context.write(new Text(word.trim().toLowerCase()), new IntWritable(1));
        }
    }
}
```

And reduce logic to following

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int count = 0;
    if(key.toString().trim().toLowerCase().equals("the")) {
        for (final IntWritable nextValue : values) {
            count += nextValue.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(count));
    }        
}
```

Comment: I found the logic is not the issue. The issue was Reducer was not called because of the method signature mismatch. After making the changes suggested by **zuxoj**, the program started working even with my own logic which I posted in the original question. Thanks to you too... :)